# mistake in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop

I am trying to insert data into a table.

This is my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Employee.dbo.Humanresources (NationalIDNumber, JobTitle, BirthDate, Gender, Hiredate)
VALUES ('131456714','Finanace Manger', '1968-06-17', ' M','2019-05-15'),
       ('154236172', 'Data Analyst' , '1970-01-14', 'F','2006-04-18'),
       ('207126133', 'Assistant Manager', '1989-11-15', 'M','2016-07-19'),
       ('319327624', 'Team Laed', '1991-12-01', ' F',' 2016-06-25')
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 36
>   String or binary data would be truncated

Please let me know what I did wrong

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the table defintion.

Comment: The length of a column value that you want to insert is greater than the defined length of the column in the CREATE statement of the table. Possibly because there is a leading space in 2 values of the column Gender. Change ' M' and ' F' to 'M' and 'F'.

Answer (score 1):

Is Hiredate a date/datetime field or a 10-character string?  If it's a 10-character string, it looks like you have a leading space in the last value shown above.  You're also missing the final closing parentheses.